# Error while importing Tensorflow. TypeError: expected bytes, descriptor found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow only for CPU in windows 10 with

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

it downloaded and installed correctly, but when i tried to import it gave me the following error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import function_pb2
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\function_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\resource_handle_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_shape_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__shape__pb2
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape_pb2.py", line 112, in <module>
    '__module__' : 'tensorflow.core.framework.tensor_shape_pb2'
TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: expected bytes, Descriptor found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59145666/typeerror-expected-bytes-descriptor-found)

Comment: I was able to solve my problem but another problem came up, I found the new solution and now I can use tensorflow. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed probuf with

```
pip install protobuf-py3
```

But another problem came up

```
import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 32, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import function_pb2
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\function_pb2.py", line 10, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
  File "C:\Users\Eloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\symbol_database.py", line 184, in <module>
    _DEFAULT = SymbolDatabase(pool=descriptor_pool.Default())
AttributeError: module 'google.protobuf.descriptor_pool' has no attribute 'Default'
```

this solved my new problem
[Getting module 'google.protobuf.descriptor_pool' has no attribute 'Default' in my python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910041/getting-module-google-protobuf-descriptor-pool-has-no-attribute-default-in-m)